# Go up in multi record block after clicking a button

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracleforms

I have a multi record block that looks like this:

[image]

What I wanted is that for example, my cursor is on the 5th record, the cursor will go up on the 4th record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*If you mean the cursor proceed to one record up after clicking or pressed on the button which's labelled as `go up!`, then right-click on the button, then move cursor to `Smart Triggers` and add `WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED` trigger ( or alternatively move cursor to `PL/SQL Editor` after right-click and add `WHEN-MOUSE-CLICK` but this way the button is only activated by mouse click while by the other way both mouse or keyboard might be used ).*

*And type `previous_record;` inside trigger to the cursor go up one record in every click( or pressing). Moreover a button could be added above the multi-record block with code `next_record;` to make the cursor go down one record for every pressing.*

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code in the when-button-pressed

```
UP;
```